# Extracting noun phrases from a text file using stanford typed parser

Tags: java, text, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I have a text which I want to extract the noun phrases from it. I can easily get the typed parser for the text that i have, but wondering how i can extract the noun phrases in the text ?

Comment: I have tried to get stanford typed parser, but still wondering which tags is represented the noun phrase !

Comment: U need NLP tools. check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889675/extract-nouns-from-text-java

Comment: Why are you using a dependency parser in the first place? A normal parse tree generator seems like that way to go for what you want.

Comment: check out my code for pulling dependency info out. It's gonna be slightly different with a syntactic parse, but you can figure it out with a few debug loops: https://gist.github.com/2562754

Answer (score 10):

You can extract noun phrases from Tree by using following code. It assumes you have parsed sentence stored in **parse** (i.e. parse is output of LexicalizedParser class apply method)

```
public static List<Tree> GetNounPhrases()
{

    List<Tree> phraseList=new ArrayList<Tree>();
    for (Tree subtree: parse)
    {

      if(subtree.label().value().equals("NP"))
      {

        phraseList.add(subtree);
        System.out.println(subtree);

      }
    }

      return phraseList;

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tagger.shtml) as well. I am not sure whether the stanford pos tagger and the tagger available in the corenlp are the same or not but I found this link to be more useful.

After PoS Tagging you will have to detect patterns like this
**(Adjective | Noun)* (Noun Preposition)? (Adjective | Noun)* Noun**

Try this [link](https://files.ifi.uzh.ch/cl/hess/classes/ecl1/termerCIE.html) for some details on Noun phrase detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stanford Core NLP for POS tagging. You could find a sample code at http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml#Usage which might be a good starting point for experimentation. You would need to give tokenize, split and pos as the properties. This outputs a list of tokens with their corresponding tags.

The entire tag list can be viwed at http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html. All the noun tags would start with NN. Performing this check would give you the required tokens.